# Genre of music used in old Amiga demo videos

Tags: similar-artists, identify-this-genre, synthpop

Many years ago I found some Amiga music in demos.

**Interference demo**

You can start at 0.35.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BWYRIV8YVdk

**Turrican 2 - Desert rocks**

It kind of also have that sound.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hn-UqDfedZA

**What I am looking for:**

- Similar music to my above examples.
- Synth, both chord like leads as well as bloppy melodic melodies.
- It does **not** need to be retro like my example happends to be.

For years I've been hoping to find this kind of music but I just can't find it. Is this kind of music completely dead?

**Question**

What is this music category called? A bonus would be to point me in the right direction at similar music, some namedropping or links.

Comment: Google 'upbeat electronic music' ymmv.

Comment: @DaveP has a good suggestion. This kind of music was popular through the 80s/90s. Some names : Soft Cell, Eurhythmics, Yazoo, Erasure. Google "Music like...." any of the above, and see where it leads you...

Answer (score 4):

*[Chiptune](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=smnPns0keDY)* is a modern music genre inspired by the songs that played on classic video game and computer consoles like the Amiga.  It uses the same kind of crudely synthesized electronic sounds featured in your clip, and often is inspired by the same 80's pop electronica that was popular when such songs were originally made.

For a recent band with a similar aesthetic, but not quite so retro, try [Ratatat](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IZAUaCdMzz8).

Comment: I agree, chiptune a.k.a. 8-bit music is the answer

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion chipmusic usually leans more into gaming consoles than home computer demo and game music. It sounds very different than music on Amiga or C64 or even Adlib / Soundblaster. I believe MOD music or tracker music would be the correct term.